# Forge API -missing IFC derivatives when checking translation result

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to translate a revit file directly from BIM360.
I posted a job like so:

```
            List<JobPayloadItem> outputs = new List<JobPayloadItem> {
                new (JobPayloadItem.TypeEnum.Ifc)
            };
            string workFlowId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            JobPayloadMisc misc = new JobPayloadMisc(workFlowId);
            JobPayloadDestination.RegionEnum destinationRegion = JobPayloadDestination.RegionEnum.US;
            JobPayloadDestination destination = new JobPayloadDestination(destinationRegion);
            JobPayload payload = new JobPayload(new JobPayloadInput(base64Urn), new JobPayloadOutput(outputs, destination), misc);
            
            m_api.Configuration.AccessToken = accessToken;
            DynamicJsonResponse response = await m_api.TranslateAsync(payload, true);
```

And when I try to check it's result with the safe urn I get in this response like this:

```
   DynamicJsonResponse result = await m_api.GetManifestAsync(base64Urn);
```

There is no IFC derivative job in the response (I put ***** instead of some private information).
Here is the response:

```
{
    "urn": "*****",
    "derivatives": {
        "0": {
            "hasThumbnail": "true",
            "overrideOutputType": "svf2",
            "children": {
                "0": {
                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/Resource/model.sdb",
                    "role": "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase",
                    "mime": "application/autodesk-db",
                    "guid": "6fac95cb-af5d-3e4f-b943-8a7f55847ff1",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "status": "success"
                },
                "1": {
                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/Resource/AECModelData.json",
                    "role": "Autodesk.AEC.ModelData",
                    "mime": "application/json",
                    "guid": "a4aac952-a3f4-031c-4113-b2d9ac2d0de6",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "status": "success"
                },
                "2": {
                    "guid": "86dcdfb0-d97d-e3d7-3404-b53abf1678b1",
                    "phaseNames": "New Construction",
                    "hasThumbnail": "true",
                    "role": "3d",
                    "name": "3D",
                    "progress": "complete",
                    "type": "geometry",
                    "viewableID": "92b5dec7-790a-45b0-a5e8-cd9f76058c3a-009a4098",
                    "status": "success",
                    "children": {
                        "0": {
                            "guid": "92b5dec7-790a-45b0-a5e8-cd9f76058c3a-009a4098",
                            "role": "3d",
                            "name": "3D",
                            "progress": "complete",
                            "camera": {
                                "0": 625.0464477539063,
                                "1": -563.9346313476563,
                                "2": 833.3741455078125,
                                "3": 96.7083740234375,
                                "4": -35.5965690612793,
                                "5": 305.0361022949219,
                                "6": -0.40824830532073977,
                                "7": 0.40824830532073977,
                                "8": 0.8164966106414795,
                                "9": 0.6307491064071655,
                                "10": 0,
                                "11": 1,
                                "12": 1
                            },
                            "type": "view",
                            "status": "success"
                        },
                        "1": {
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/Resource/3D View/3D/3D.svf",
                            "role": "graphics",
                            "mime": "application/autodesk-svf",
                            "guid": "fbec8b0f-58d6-2e86-30c8-211e4056efeb",
                            "type": "resource"
                        },
                        "2": {
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/Resource/3D View/3D/3D1.png",
                            "role": "thumbnail",
                            "mime": "image/png",
                            "guid": "c70aa596-d404-714f-6795-9276087c3800",
                            "type": "resource",
                            "resolution": {
                                "0": 100,
                                "1": 100
                            },
                            "status": "success"
                        },
                        "3": {
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/Resource/3D View/3D/3D2.png",
                            "role": "thumbnail",
                            "mime": "image/png",
                            "guid": "6ef65d1a-4a59-111d-f1ec-4e543bd2712b",
                            "type": "resource",
                            "resolution": {
                                "0": 200,
                                "1": 200
                            },
                            "status": "success"
                        },
                        "4": {
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/Resource/3D View/3D/3D4.png",
                            "role": "thumbnail",
                            "mime": "image/png",
                            "guid": "2c06739e-5164-4f6d-450e-c8833fd2a2ba",
                            "type": "resource",
                            "resolution": {
                                "0": 400,
                                "1": 400
                            },
                            "status": "success"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "3": {
                    "isMasterView": true,
                    "phaseNames": "New Construction",
                    "hasThumbnail": "true",
                    "role": "3d",
                    "children": {
                        "0": {
                            "guid": "c884ae1b-61e7-4f9d-0001-719e20b22d0b-009a40af",
                            "role": "3d",
                            "name": "New Construction",
                            "progress": "complete",
                            "camera": {
                                "0": 594.0901489257813,
                                "1": -500.6220397949219,
                                "2": 819.0045166015625,
                                "3": 95.86978149414063,
                                "4": -2.4016761779785158,
                                "5": 320.78411865234377,
                                "6": -0.40824830532073977,
                                "7": 0.40824830532073977,
                                "8": 0.8164966106414795,
                                "9": 0.3480738401412964,
                                "10": 0,
                                "11": 1,
                                "12": 1
                            },
                            "type": "view",
                            "status": "success"
                        },
                        "1": {
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/Resource/3D View/*****/New Construction/New Construction.svf",
                            "role": "graphics",
                            "mime": "application/autodesk-svf",
                            "guid": "3572dadf-f7d8-cf8b-a625-967f27309e85",
                            "type": "resource"
                        },
                        "2": {
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/Resource/3D View/*****/New Construction/New Construction1.png",
                            "role": "thumbnail",
                            "mime": "image/png",
                            "guid": "a3c19573-8948-7ae0-fb5c-75cab1d0e87a",
                            "type": "resource",
                            "resolution": {
                                "0": 100,
                                "1": 100
                            },
                            "status": "success"
                        },
                        "3": {
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/Resource/3D View/*****/New Construction/New Construction2.png",
                            "role": "thumbnail",
                            "mime": "image/png",
                            "guid": "86d53dd2-82c8-1948-5997-00ebf6078ed7",
                            "type": "resource",
                            "resolution": {
                                "0": 200,
                                "1": 200
                            },
                            "status": "success"
                        },
                        "4": {
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/Resource/3D View/*****/New Construction/New Construction4.png",
                            "role": "thumbnail",
                            "mime": "image/png",
                            "guid": "7e36c074-8997-d941-4dc3-6a72fcdf3b9b",
                            "type": "resource",
                            "resolution": {
                                "0": 400,
                                "1": 400
                            },
                            "status": "success"
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "New Construction",
                    "guid": "4b621e7d-f520-422b-95fd-645b8690168a",
                    "progress": "complete",
                    "type": "geometry",
                    "viewableID": "c884ae1b-61e7-4f9d-0001-719e20b22d0b-009a40af",
                    "status": "success"
                }
            },
            "name": "*****.rvt",
            "progress": "complete",
            "messages": {
                "0": {
                    "type": "warning",
                    "code": "Revit-MissingLink",
                    "message": {
                        "0": "Missing link files: {0}",
                        "1": "08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg"
                    }
                }
            },
            "outputType": "svf",
            "status": "success"
        },
        "1": {
            "children": {
                "0": {
                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/preview1.png",
                    "role": "thumbnail",
                    "mime": "image/png",
                    "guid": "db899ab5-939f-e250-d79d-2d1637ce4565",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "resolution": {
                        "0": 100,
                        "1": 100
                    },
                    "status": "success"
                },
                "1": {
                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/preview2.png",
                    "role": "thumbnail",
                    "mime": "image/png",
                    "guid": "3f6c118d-f551-7bf0-03c9-8548d26c9772",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "resolution": {
                        "0": 200,
                        "1": 200
                    },
                    "status": "success"
                },
                "2": {
                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:*****/output/preview4.png",
                    "role": "thumbnail",
                    "mime": "image/png",
                    "guid": "4e751806-0920-ce32-e9fd-47c3cec21536",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "resolution": {
                        "0": 400,
                        "1": 400
                    },
                    "status": "success"
                }
            },
            "progress": "complete",
            "outputType": "thumbnail",
            "status": "success"
        }
    },
    "hasThumbnail": "true",
    "messages": {
        "0": {
            "type": "warning",
            "code": "Revit-MissingLink",
            "message": {
                "0": "Missing link files: {0}",
                "1": "08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg, 08.12.2019.   *****.dwg"
            }
        }
    },
    "progress": "99% complete",
    "type": "manifest",
    "region": "US",
    "version": "1.0",
    "status": "inprogress"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you request the IFC translation, you should get a response that the IFC translation request was accepted (success). Later when you request the manifest, you will not see the IFC output until it is fully processed. In your example, you see the SVF2 output because this one is mandatory on BIM360 for RVT files. The IFC entry will appear when the IFC file is ready. Since you requested the IFC sometime ago now, do ask for the manifest again, it should be there by now. If not, please contact us at forge.help at autodesk.com and share the URN which failed and we will take a look at out logs to isolate the issue.